# Explicit form of strange attractors

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Are there any examples of continuous-time dynamical systems possessing strange attractors for which there exist *explicit formulas* describing these attractors?

Many thanks in advance and apologies if this question is too naive or not sufficiently well-posed: I have just began learning about the attractors.

Comment: What do you consider to be an *explicit formula* here? After all strange attractors are fractals and even “normal” fractals cannot be described by something that I would call an explicit formula. From another point of view: Is there something that you would consider an explicit formula that describes, e.g., the Cantor Set?